# Ionic: Cordova GetPicture FileURL contain Number at the place of file name

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I am selecting the image from galary and saving into app directory, but i am facing issue when image selected the file name in url is random number like:

```
"/media/external/images/media/26183"
```

I am not getting the exact file name, by this reason when file is going to copy file not found error is throwing My Code for fetching and saving are:

```
     $scope.ChangeProfile = function() {
      var options = {
        quality: 30,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
         encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
         mediaType:Camera.MediaType.PICTURE
      };

      navigator.camera.getPicture( OnCameraSuccess, OnCameraError, options);


    };
 function OnCameraSuccess(imageURI) {
          console.log(imageURI);
           window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageURI,OnSucessFilePath, onErrorFilePath); 
          }
          function onErrorFilePath(error){
              console.log(error);
          }
          function OnSucessFilePath(fileEntry){
              console.log(fileEntry);
              var FilePath=fileEntry.nativeURL;
          var name = FilePath.substr(FilePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
          var namePath = FilePath.substr(0, FilePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
            var newName = "Profile_Pic";
          $cordovaFile.removeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, newName)
          .then(function (success) {
              console.log(success);
          }, function (error) {
              console.log(error);
          });
          // var newName = makeid() + name;
          $cordovaFile.copyFile(namePath, name, cordova.file.dataDirectory, newName)
          .then(function(info) {
          console.log(info);
            ProfileImage.Image = cordova.file.dataDirectory+newName;
            $scope.PicUpload = true;
              },
            function(err){
            console.log(err);
            });
          }
           function OnCameraError(err){
            console.log(err);
            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'error in Loading', duration:500});
          }
```

please tell me where i am doing wrong, i have spend lot of time on this, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you run you application on Android platform, so I think you need to resolve native uri. You can use [this plugin](https://github.com/hiddentao/cordova-plugin-filepath.git) to resolve it.

*example:*

```
window.FilePath.resolveNativePath(YourNativeURI,
                function (result) {
                    console.log('Resolving file path: ' + result);                        
                }, function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
```